# 2sxc 403 Errors on sub-site when trying to edit

Tags: 2sxc

running into a weird error using 2sxc on a subsite.

I have a basic module on the page that works fine for end users but is having problems editing.

When a local(subsite) admin tries to edit they get a 403 error for:
https://www.PRIMARY.com/SUBSITE/api/2sxc/cms/edit/load?appId=12

The same module works fine if I log in as a super user OR log into the main site as an admin

Its driving me crazy. Any help would be appreciated.

DNN 9.10.2
2SXC 14.7.4

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure the permissions are configured correctly? just in case you configured permissions in the App and used a group-id or something which only exists on the main site...

Comment: For any more help, we would need a lot more details about the problem.

Comment: BTW: I believe this is fixed in 14.09 or 14.10